# Possible to convert a linux installation to .VDI or ISO format?

Tags: linux, conversion, vmware

I have an Oracle Peoplesoft installation set up on some virtual machines (they were in OVM format). I'd like to copy them over so they work in VirtualBox… would it be possible to convert them to a format VirtualBox can understand?

I found a guide that lets you convert a single hard drive in Linux to ISO and then convert that to VDI, but the problem with that is that it only works on a single drive—I'd like to convert the whole filesystem. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can copy a Linux installation between two real machines (e.g. with Partimage or dd) then you can do that to a virtual machine too. I mean instead of converting the installation and then booting it, you would create an empty virtual machine, boot it with a boot CD, and copy the old installation to the new empty virtual machine.